# mutliple entry widgets and one button widget in tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, init, self

I am trying to make two entry boxes and an 'OK' button that processes both entries:
    I don't understand the **init**() function or the reason 'self' has to be include in doing this.
I want to access the entries outside this class and mainloop. The entries should be string type.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("550x145+500+300")

class myDose:
    def __init__(self):

        l1 = Label(text="Enter the prescription dose to three (3) decimal places [cGy]").pack()
        e1 = Entry(root)
        e1.pack()

        l2 = Label(text="Save new excel file as...").pack()
        e2 = Entry(root)
        e2.pack()

        l3 = Label(text="click 'OK', and then close window.").pack()

        b = Button(root, text="OK", command=submit)
        b.pack()

    def submit(self):
        print(e1.get())
        print(e2.get())

D = myDose()
root.mainloop()

#I want to access the entries, e1 and e2, outside the mainloop
print(D.e1)
print(D.e2)
```

Comment: By "outside the mainloop" that means "after the window is destroyed". Are you aware of that? Or are you asking how to run code after `mainloop`, but with the window still visible?

Comment: I have written functions above this class. They depend on this e1 variable. That's why I want to get the user's entry number 1. Below this class, in my program, I have code that is like a main() function (i.e. it is where my code begins to run) and that depends on the e2.

Comment: Do they depend on the e1 _widget_, or the value that was input into the widget?

Comment: @BryanOakley so basically I just want to use those entry values in my code elsewhere

Comment: the string that is entered into the widget @BryanOakley

Comment: If you have other functions in your script, you should call them in this class. For all practical purposes, the Tkinter application is your program. You are attempting to construct your program in a way that is severely contrary to the normal, functional way, and it is bound to fail, as you are seeing. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: @Michael Do you want other parts of your program to do GUI stuff, or is this window the only GUI component of your program?

Comment: @PM2Ring there is one other part in my code where I just get a directory by using askopenfilename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `mainloop` doesn't exit until the root window is destroyed. Once the root window is destroyed you can no longer access the widgets inside the root window. You can, however, access non-widget attributes of the object.

If that is what you want -- to destroy the window and have access to the values in the widget -- you need to save the values before destroying the window.

For example, in your submit you could save the values like this:

```
def submit(self):
    self.data = {"e1": self.e1.get(), "e2": self.e2.get()}
```

Once the window is destroyed,  you still have a reference to the application object, so you can still access the non-widget attributes of the class:

```
...
D = myDose(root)
root.mainloop()

print D.data["e1"]
print D.data["e2"]
```

---

Based on comments to the original question, you mention that later in your code you'll need to use `askopenfilename`. if that is the case, you should reconsider the need to run code after `mainloop`. Tkinter is designed to have a root window created exactly once, and for the program to exit immediately after `mainloop` exits.

You can write programs however you want, but I think your code will be easier to maintain and modify over the long run if you stick to normal design patterns. Move your "real" code into a method of the app class and that will eliminate all of the problems associated with widgets being destroyed.

Comment: @Michael - Please just keep in mind that knowing what you mean isn't equivalent to agreeing that you are constructing your program in a reasonable way. I recommend researching Tkinter applications - specifically, how to access a data model with such applications - so that you can write your program correctly. This will make it much easier to work with your code later on.

Comment: @Michael - That is true, but if "it works" remains your only criterion, it will become much more difficult to work this code with later on. Consider carefully whether you'd really like to abandon Python's emphasis on readable code and canonical approaches.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: after seeing newer comments on the original question, you're right that this is a poor design. I've updated my answer to hopefully address this. Now that we know the OP is going to use Tkinter more than just at startup we should encourage a better overall architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fundamentally flawed. `mainloop()` does what it says: starts a loop. The lines that follow it will not be executed until that loop is over - meaning, until your application has closed. Since you already have a class with Tkinter stuff in it, just finish the move to an OO approach:

```
from tkinter import *

class myDose:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.geometry("550x145+500+300")

        self.l1 = Label(root, text="Enter the prescription dose to three (3) decimal places [cGy]")
        self.l1.pack()
        self.e1 = Entry(root)
        self.e1.pack()

        self.l2 = Label(root, text="Save new excel file as...")
        self.l2.pack()
        self.e2 = Entry(root)
        self.e2.pack()

        self.l3 = Label(root, text="click 'OK', and then close window.")
        self.l3.pack()

        self.b = Button(root, text="OK", command=self.submit)
        self.b.pack()

    def submit(self):
        print(self.e1.get())
        print(self.e2.get())

root = Tk()
D = myDose(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I recommend looking more thoroughly into how fundamental concepts like objects and classes work before creating a full GUI application.

Comment: What do you mean by an OO approach? I need to access those entries below the line 'root.mainloop' my other code depends on getting those values @TigerhawkT3

Comment: going print(D.e1) below root.mainloop gives me some random value like .6745325

Comment: @Michael Did you try doing `print(D.e1.get())` after `root.mainloop()` in TigerhawkT3's version of your script?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, and it doesn't like that:_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".4744112"

Comment: @Michael "OO" means [object oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I don't know how being told to do OO is going to help me pull those values below the mainloop

Comment: As I said, "accessing those entries below the line `root.mainloop()`" means that you will be trying to access widgets from an application after it has closed. That plan is fundamentally flawed. If you have an existing data model already, access it from within your Tkinter application in whatever way is appropriate (import the module, pass in an object, instantiate a class, whatever).

Comment: _" meaning, until your application has closed. "_ -- that wording is imprecise. mainloop runs until the root widow is destroyed. The application itself can still be alive (or "open", or "running", whatever terminology you prefer). Also the widgets will be destroyed, the object that `D` points to will still exist.

Comment: @BryanOakley - That may be the case, but is it best practice to rely on that?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: It depends how you do it. If you maintain references to the dead widgets (by binding them to instance attributes) I agree that it's a bit icky. :) But in my version I'm using locals to create the GUI, and only using instance attributes to store the string data. True, those attributes _are_ Tkinter StringVar objects, but they aren't actually bound to the GUI per se, so it's ok for them to persist after `__init__` returns.

Comment: @PM2Ring - It sounds like you aren't so much explaining how it works as explaining how it manages to avoid failing. :P

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I agree that it's a _much_ better design to make the GUI class the hub of the program, but there's nothing intrinsically wrong with adding the GUI as a component to a program which is primarily a more traditional CLI-oriented design. It's really no different to calling a dialog widget in a CLI script, except that it's using a custom-made dialog, rather than a pre-built one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix.

The problem with both your version and TigerhawkT3's modified version is that when you close the window the `Entry` widgets are no longer valid, so you need to save the data before closing the window. One way to do that is to attach Tkinter `StringVar`s to the `Entry` widgets. The values in the `StringVar`s will be available after the window is closed.

```
import tkinter as tk

class myDose:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.geometry("550x145+500+300")

        l = tk.Label(root, text="Enter the prescription dose to three (3) decimal places [cGy]")
        l.pack()
        self.dosage = tk.StringVar()
        e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=self.dosage)
        e.pack()

        l = tk.Label(root, text="Save new excel file as...")
        l.pack()
        self.savename = tk.StringVar() 
        e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=self.savename)
        e.pack()

        l = tk.Label(root, text="Enter the data and then close window.")
        l.pack()

        root.mainloop()

D = myDose(tk.Tk())

print(D.dosage.get())
print(D.savename.get())
```

Note that I've changed the `import` statement. It's much cleaner to *not* do

```
from tkinter import *
```

as that clutters your namespace with over 100 names, leading to potential name collisions.

---

The `__init__()` function is a method of the `myDose` class. A class's `__init__()` method is called when an instance of that class is created. In your code that happens when you do

```
D = myDose()
```

In my version it's when this line is executed:

```
D = myDose(tk.Tk())
```

which first creates the Tkinter root window which is then passed to `myDose`; that root window is then available to my `__init__()` as its `root` argument.

The name `self` is used inside the class to refer to the current class instance. Outside the class we need to use the actual name we assigned the instance to, which in this case is `D`.

Comment: When you say "the problem with the earlier version", what "earlier version" are you talking about? Answers can be in a different order than when you write your answer. Are you referring to the version in the question, or in one of the other answers? Can you be more specific in your answer?